# Sending email using Gmail client API for Android bounce back with error

Tags: android, email, gmail, gmail-api, mime-message

The client library offers constructors for creating an email request under `Gmail.Users.Messages.Send` :

```
protected Gmail.Users.Messages.Send(java.lang.String userId, Message content)
protected Gmail.Users.Messages.Send(java.lang.String userId,
                     Message content, com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent)
```

When I use the first, I use the following code to translate the `MimeMessage` to `gmail.model.Message` type :

```
Message createMessage(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mimeMessage.writeTo(bytes);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
    return message;
}
```

And sends the email successfully.

On the other hand, when I have a large attachment, I use the second (resumable upload) constructor and convert the `MimeMessage` to `InputStreamContent` and use `null` for the second argument but the message bounce back with error:

```
An error occured. Your message was not sent.
------=_Part_0_987504577.1456605774444
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-
```

(when I use the second constructor with no attachment the result is the same)

Here is the `MimeMessage` (without attachment for simplification) :

```
From: mail@mail.com
Reply-To: mail@mail.com
To: mail@mail.com
Message-ID: <235235322.1.1456605773066@localhost>
Subject: subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_987504577.1456605774444"

------=_Part_0_987504577.1456605774444
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

body
------=_Part_0_987504577.1456605774444--
```

Since it's sent successfully when using the first constructor I assume one of the following :

1. The first constructor adds a missing attribute which the second doesn't
2. I miss something when I use the seconds constructor (but.. what? the data is sent)

Comment: I think its not supposed to be the `MimeMessage`, it should only have the attachment. The [overridden Send method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/Gmail.Users.Messages.Send.html#Gmail.Users.Messages.Send(java.lang.String,%20com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message,%20com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent)) already contains the `Message` along with the other parts, the 3rd parameter is specific for the  media.

Comment: @adjuremods , I've tried this before, but according to the (poor) documentation this is only for Message media metadata (or `null`), but not the message itself : `content - the Message media metadata or null if none`, unlike the first constructor which its message parameter description is `content - the Message`

Comment: My guess is its still the actual message, I mean, why override a method if the `Message` parameter is different, right?

Comment: @adjuremods the override is for using another upload type (`simple` vs `resumable`), when looking over the library implementation it's more easy to see the difference between the constructors.